# How to safely dual boot ubuntu alongside windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, ssd, uefi, dualboot

Firstly, here is my device config: A 120 GB SSD that has Windows 10 installed, a separate 1TB HDD (now used for storage), UEFI type BIOS.

I am considering to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on the same SSD that has Windows. What are the steps I need to follow to do that?

Also, shall I reconsider, for any reason, to install Ubuntu on the HDD instead?

Please feel free to describe anything that I need to know, I don't want to mess up with my machine.

Comment: What is "UEFI type BIOS"?

Comment: @grawity Likely means they have UEFI... unfortunately, OEMs have chosen the route of incorrect terminology to make it "easier" on consumers; as such, OEMs refer to UEFI as BIOS _(it'd be interesting to have an OEM try to square that circle in an explanation)_.  **Tushar:** You're going to run out of space fairly quickly trying to dual boot a 120GB SSD, unless you're storing user data on a separate drive and aren't installing a lot of programs. There's likely only ~100GB of usable space, 10% must stay empty for Over-Provisioning, leaving 90GB for Windows, Ubuntu, and all user data for both.

Comment: Thanks @JW0914 but what if I allocate 70GB for Ubuntu? Is that gonna be enough for Ubuntu? Do I have the options to install larger apps on separate drive like in windows?
I wont be using windows that often and whatever I need, are already installed leaving me 80GB of free space.

Comment: @Tushar You currently have 80GB of free space?  Min. system partition size for Windows is 32GB, and bi-annual updates will require another ~11GB, so ~45GB would be around the min for normal use.  You can shrink it further by removing functionality, and I would recommend checking out threads on the [MSFN forum](https://msfn.org/board/) if you choose that route.  A >=256GB SSD would be the recommended route, eliminating the size constraints, and with Black Friday this Friday and Cyber Monday a week from today, you'll be able to pick up an NVMe or MLC/TLC SSD for fairly cheap (avoid QLC SSDs).

Answer (score 0):

- I did this on my laptop with UEFI a few days ago. Here's what I did:

  - Shrink the windows 10 partition to make space for Ubuntu, I shrank about 30 GB from it (you can do this through windows disk
    management)
  - Boot to a USB flashed with the copy of Ubuntu
  - If you need a swap partition, select "something else" on the installation type page. From there, create two partitions, one for
    swap, the other for your actual OS (ext4).
  - If you don't need a swap partition, just hit "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10". Verify it does install to the correct
    partition though.
  - Follow the rest of the steps in the installation and you'll be able to select an OS to boot from once you restart.

Comment: Why in the world would you disable Secure Boot when Ubuntu [supports](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot) it?  If it doesn't automatically boot, you'll need to add it as a Secure Boot option in the UEFI settings (usually on the boot page)

Comment: Personally I don't need secure boot, so I disable it for anything that isn't Windows. Edited.

Comment: You don't need a security feature that prevents malware from affecting the bootloader of an OS?

Comment: Thanks @JW0914 I could install it without disabling the secure boot.

Comment: How can I get/install a WiFi adapter without internet connection? I cannot connect to the internet if I don't connect to WiFi.

Comment: @Tushar See [**Installing packages without an internet connection**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Installing_packages_without_an_Internet_connection)